# Why method annotated with @ModelAttribute could not pick up model attributes added through view

Tags: spring-mvc, model, modelattribute, spring-form

Why didn't the `model.asMap()` in method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` (i.e `AM1` here) didn't return any model data but in the `@RequestMapping`(i.e `HM1` here) it does.

View:

```
<form:form action="SignupValidate.htm" modelAttribute="ma_CustomerTO">
CustName:<form:input path="CustName" />
CustSpouse:<form:input path="CustSpouse" />
```

I have submitted the form with fields values `CustName`=abc `CustSpouse`=xyz

Contoller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Customer")
public class CustomerController {
      //-------------------------------------//
      @ModelAttribute("ma_CustomerTO")
      public CustomerTO AM1(Model model) {
          logger.debug(model.asMap());   //-----> does not print the model attributes from view???
          CustomerTO customer=new CustomerTO(); 
          customer.setCustName("Sheldon");
          customer.setCustSpouse("Amy");
          logger.debug(model.asMap());
        return customer;
      }
      //-------------------------------------//
      @RequestMapping("/SignupValidate.htm")
      public ModelAndView HM1(Model model,@ModelAttribute("ma_CustomerTO") CustomerTO customer){
          logger.debug(model.asMap());//-----> but this one prints
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have think possibly this should be happening. The `@ModelAttribute` on method would not create a attribute for model until the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Every method with `@ModelAttribute` annotated will be called before receiving request from client in order to initialize model for your view. That's the use of method leveled `@ModelAttribute`.

The model in your `@ModelAttribute` method doesn't know about `ma_CustomerTO` because it is called before your `SignupValidate.htm` method is processed